# Why is running cargo bench faster than running release build?

Tags: rust, benchmarking

I want to benchmark my Rust programs, and was comparing some alternatives to do that. I noted, however, that when running a benchmark with `cargo bench` and the `bencher` crate, the code runs consistently faster than when running a production build (`cargo build --release`) with the same code. For example:

Main code:

```
use dot_product;
const N: usize = 1000000;

use std::time;
fn main() {
    let start = time::Instant::now();
    dot_product::rayon_parallel([1; N].to_vec(), [2; N].to_vec());
    println!("Time: {:?}", start.elapsed());
}
```

Average time: ~20ms

Benchmark code:

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate bencher;

use dot_product;

use bencher::Bencher;

const N: usize = 1000000;

fn parallel(bench: &mut Bencher) {
    bench.iter(|| dot_product::rayon_parallel([1; N].to_vec(), [2; N].to_vec()))
}

benchmark_group!(benches, sequential, parallel);
benchmark_main!(benches);
```

Time: `5,006,199 ns/iter (+/- 1,320,975)`

I tried the same with some other programs and `cargo bench` gives consistently faster results. Why could this happen?

Comment: cause your benchmark do nothing.

Comment: `bench.iter(|| black_box(dot_product::rayon_parallel([1; N].to_vec(), [2; N].to_vec())))`

Comment: Did you check the resolution of `std::time`?

Comment: worked, actually had to black box the `[1; N]` part though. Thanks!

Comment: @danitrod Can you try run your original code 1000 times and calculate how much it takes? Benchers run code a lot of times then divide total time by number of iterations.

Comment: @AngelicosPhosphoros Even running the compiled version 1000 times it was significantly slower than with bencher, the problem was that I was not black boxing my function so the bencher was removing dead code as the answer explained.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As the comments suggested, you should use [`criterion::black_box()`](https://docs.rs/criterion/0.3.4/criterion/fn.black_box.html) on all (final) results in the benchmarking code. This function does nothing - and simply gives back its only parameter - but is opaque to the optimizer, so the compiler has to assume the function does *something* with the input.

When not using `black_box()`, the benchmarking code doesn't actually do anything, as the compiler is able to figure out that the results of your code are unused and no side-effects can be observed. So it removes all your code during dead-code elimination and what you end up benchmarking is the benchmarking-suite itself.

Comment: `std::hint::black_box` should also work